# Excel/Google Sheets: sum multiple values that match a formula

Tags: excel

Here's what I use to display the content of the cell in the sheet '2015', range $C$2:$C$12 if row matches the content of $A5 in the range '2015'!:$B$2:$B$12

```
=INDEX('2015'!$C$2:$C$12;MATCH($A5;'2015'!$B$2:$B$12;0))
```

The problem is I have duplicates in the range '2015'!:B2:B12 and I'd like to sum the values in C2:C12 if there are matches with same name in '2015'!$B$2:$B$12.

I tried to change the formula in:

```
=SUMIF('2015'!$C$2:$C$12;MATCH($A6;'2015'!$B$2:$B$12;0))
```

... but that returns 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `SUMIF` you don't need the `MATCH` function

The correct syntax is as follows:

`=SUMIF(range;criteria;sum_range)`

....so in your case try like this:

`=SUMIF('2015'!$B$2:$B$12;$A6;'2015'!$C$2:$C$12)`